# Unique ID for related records in a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to allocate a unique RecordID (ImportID) to multiple rows in a table. We are importing a text file which contain related transactional information but variable record types and I want to be able to track the import by the unique ID. By way of example we import a text file into a rawtext_table (longtext field type) and then make use of SUBSTRING selects according to the file specs to extract the relevant data. The text file, when generated, groups the related transactions - so records relating to transaction 1 will follow in each subsequent row and then record 2 with related transactions etc etc - the problem here is that the sequencing on of the transaction could be the same based on the record type. The raw file would output the following extract using a substring select:
NWR0001 - Joe Soap; ADR0001 - 10 WhoknowsWhere; CNT0001 - 0112001234
NWR0002 - Another Soap; ADR0002 - 10 SomeOtherPlace; CNT0002 - 0115553458
REV0001 - Marie Soap; ADR0001 - 10 WeNowKnowWhere; CNT0001 - 0118881111

The LEFT 3 char is the record types and come in a specific sequence and are inserted in various tables based on the record type, but not all records in the file will have all the types. Records will start with with either NWR or REV and end with the last type related to the transaction. As an example, in the data above the REV001 is a revision record, but has the same ID if we utilised position 4-7 which is the transaction ID.
My requirements is to have a query / stored procedure in MySQL that can step through the records and on each sequence change / block of related transactions allocate a unique ID and insert this into the various tables based on the Record Type (insert statement). So for the information provided above, NWR0001, ADR0001, CNT0001 would all have an ImportID of 1 and NWR0002, ADR0002, CNT0002 and ImportID of 2 and REV0001, ADR0001, CNT0001 would have an ImportID of 3

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "unique RecordID (ImportID) to multiple rows in a table" -- then it is a plain `INDEX`, not `UNIQUE`.

Comment: I require an actual Integer value not an index - the record set for all related transactions require a unique record ID which I can then use in queries

Comment: Multiple rows will have the same "id"?  OK.  That column can (should?) have a non-unique `INDEX`.  Or, maybe I am confused.  Can you provide a short sample of the rows in question.